# SQL conditional selection Oracle sql

Tags: variables, conditional-statements, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wrote a query that look like this:

```
select 
   q_id, 
   s_id, no, 
   date,
   nm,
   p 
from 
   (select * from table1 where q_id = 100) tb1 
left join
   (select * from table2 where q_id = 100 and date = left(getdate(),11)) tb2 
   on tb2.s_id = tb1.s_id 
join 
   table3 tb3 
   on tb3.s_id = tb1.s_id
order 
   by no ASC;
```

I am putting this into a java controller, and q_id will be the input variable. Is there anyway I can modify the query so that I assign value to q_id (q_id = 100) once instead of twice and still achieve the same table result?

Comment: Tag the correct database that you are using

Comment: There is no `getdate()` function in Oracle. Which DBMS are you **really** using?

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL Developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the same q_id column in the WHERE clause of your tb1 and tb2 in-line views, you should be joining tb1 and tb2 on that criteria. Then, you'll only need one WHERE condition referencing q_id.

Also, as a_horse_with_no_name commented, I'm not quite sure what you're attempting to accomplish with the get_date() function. For my example, I assumed you were trying to filter results by only returning those for the current day. For that, I used sysdate and the TRUNC function. If you're trying to accomplish something else -- modify the WHERE clause accordingly.

As a side note, I recommend only using explicit variable referencing and avoiding 'SELECT *', especially when asking questions on stack exchange. With that being said, I was not sure which table the variables 'nm','no', and 'p' were coming from. I assumed they were from table 3.

```
SELECT 
   TB1.q_id, 
   TB1.s_id,
   TB2.date,
   TB3.no,
   TB3.nm,
   TB3.p
FROM table1 TB1
INNER JOIN table3 TB3
    ON TB1.s_id = tb3.s_id
LEFT JOIN table2 TB2
    ON TB1.s_id = TB2.s_id
        AND TB1.q_id = TB2.q_id
WHERE TRUNC(TB2.date) = TRUNC(sysdate)
    AND TB1.q_id = 100
ORDER BY
    TB3.no ASC
;
```

If your tables are indexed properly, there shouldn't be a performance hit by losing the pre-filtered in-line views.

Comment: I can't join on q_id because the first two tables are many to many relationships (many s_id to many q_id), that's the reason why I filtered on q_id first before joining the first two tables, and then join on s_id. I can't do it the other way around (filter on q_id and join on s_id) for the purpose of what I need to achieve. Ideally I would join on the q_id and s_id combination, which will be unique, but I tried that and it returned an empty tabe.

Comment: It worked with joining on two columns! I probably made some mistakes earlier. Thanks and thanks for the suggestions on dates.